# How can we encrypt specific column data of parquet using pyspark

Tags: azure, pyspark, encryption, parquet, azure-synapse

There is a requirement in my project to encrypt some of PII columns data while writing data in a parquet file. To write the data in parquet file, Azure Synapse pyspark notebook is being used.

Not getting any references on the internet. Any leads would be very helpful.

Comment: There are loads of example on how to encrypt a column on the internet https://www.databricks.com/notebooks/enforcing-column-level-encryption.html I've used this approach with feret, the standard spark documentation on column encryption is here https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.2/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#columnar-encryption

Comment: @Jon , using above reference posted one answer beow as per the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using the below implementation. You can try anyone based on your scope

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

class DataFrameMasker:
    def __init__(self, df: DataFrame):
        self.df = df
    
    def mask_columns(self, columns_to_mask: dict):
        masked_df = self.df
        
        for column_name, masking_strategy in columns_to_mask.items():
            if masking_strategy == "hash":
                masked_df = self._mask_hash(masked_df, column_name)
            elif masking_strategy == "random":
                masked_df = self._mask_random(masked_df, column_name)
            elif masking_strategy=="column_masker":
                masked_df = self.mask_rows(masked_df, column_name)
            # Add more masking strategies here if needed
        
        return masked_df
    
    def _mask_hash(self, df: DataFrame, column_name: str) -> DataFrame:
        masked_df = df.withColumn(column_name, F.sha2(F.col(column_name), 256))
        return masked_df
    
    def _mask_random(self, df: DataFrame, column_name: str) -> DataFrame:
        masked_df = df.withColumn(column_name, F.expr("substring(md5(cast(rand() as string)), 0, 10)"))
        return masked_df

    def mask_rows(self, df: DataFrame, columns_name: str) -> DataFrame:
        masked_df = df.withColumn(
                columns_name,
                expr(f"CASE WHEN {columns_name} IS NOT NULL THEN 'xxxxxxx' ELSE NULL END")
            )
        
        return masked_df

# Create a sample DataFrame
data = [("Subash", "K", "subashk@example.com"),
        ("Test", "Message", "testmessage@example.com")]

columns = ["first_name", "last_name", "email"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Initialize the DataFrameMasker with the DataFrame
masker = DataFrameMasker(df)

# Define columns to mask and their masking strategy
columns_to_mask = {
    "first_name": "hash",
    "last_name": "random",
    "email": "column_masker"
}

# Mask specified columns
masked_df = masker.mask_columns(columns_to_mask)

# Show the masked DataFrame
masked_df.show()
```

You can check other masking methods as hashing is a one-way process

[image]

and also check Dynamic Data masking in Synapse
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, it did the correct job for generating hash value but its one-way function. But the requirement is for encryption as well as decryption.

Comment: @Prayag15 I would recommend posting another question since your ask was specifically focused on encrypting the data. If it helped your objective, please upvote it as an answer so that it can help others in the community

Comment: Sure, Subash !!

Comment: Added information is with respect to dedicated SQL Pool. Although I have tried one method to achieve this for both encryption and decryption, posting it below. Please upvote if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Below code can help to encrypt and decrypt PII data using Fernet library. Generated Fernet key can be stored in secret and can be pulled at any point in time for decryption.

```
# Generate key using Fernet library
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = Fernet.generate_key()

#Define Encrypt User Defined Function 

def encrypt_val(clear_text,MASTER_KEY):
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
    f = Fernet(MASTER_KEY)
    clear_text_b=bytes(clear_text, 'utf-8')
    cipher_text = f.encrypt(clear_text_b)
    cipher_text = str(cipher_text.decode('ascii'))
    return cipher_text

# Define decrypt user defined function 
def decrypt_val(cipher_text,MASTER_KEY):
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
    f = Fernet(MASTER_KEY)
    clear_val=f.decrypt(cipher_text.encode()).decode()
    return clear_val 

# Create dataframe
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

columns = ["Name","Phone"]
data = [("Tom", "8989767656"), ("Jhon", "9997878676"), ("Sam", "8990344323")]

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Enc').getOrCreate()
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

dfFromRDD1 = rdd.toDF()

columns = ["Name","Phone"]
df = rdd.toDF(columns)  

# Apply encryption  
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, lit, md5
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
# Register UDF's
encrypt = udf(encrypt_val, StringType())
decrypt = udf(decrypt_val, StringType())
# Fetch key from secrets
# encryptionKey = dbutils.preview.secret.get(scope = "encrypt", key = 
"fernetkey")
encryptionKey = key
# Encrypt the data 
#df = spark.table("Test_Encryption")
encrypted = df.withColumn("Phone", encrypt("Phone",lit(encryptionKey)))
encrypted.show()

# Apply decryption
decrypted = encrypted.withColumn("Phone", 
decrypt("Phone",lit(encryptionKey)))
decrypted.show()
```